# pgAdmin Query Tool throws error when I try to run multiple statements

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I'm very new to PostgreSql and still learning the ropes.

I have a really long script for setting up a new copy of my database. It creates functions, runs them, does some inserts and a bunch of other stuff. When I try to run this entire script in the pgAdminIII Query Tool, it throws an error that doesn't seem to make sense.

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ""
LINE 18: /*
         ^
```

This error gets thrown right after the first alter function owner statement which is after the first create function statement.

If I take each statement out and run them individually then everything runs OK. What gives?

Lines before error:

```
ALTER FUNCTION table_exists(text) OWNER TO postgres;
```

Lines at error:

```
/*
-- Function     : column_exists(text, text)
-- Function output  : true / false
*/
```

Lines after error:

```
CREATE FUNCTION column_exists(tablename text, columnname text)
RETURNS boolean AS $$

BEGIN
    RETURN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = $1 AND column_name = $2);
END;

$$LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Can you paste the lines before and after the error is thrown?

Comment: Can you run the script in psql? The syntax all looks good as far as I can see - is it possible there are non-visible characters in the script that are causing the error?

Comment: Maybe an escaping issue? As already mentioned, the syntax is fine, is there any unsecaped " or ' that may be breaking the script or is a " or ' missing?

Comment: Shouldn't be an escaping issue or a non-visible script because if I run the statements individually then it seems to be fine. I even tried removing statements one by one starting from the end but it still hits the same error at the same line.

Comment: When you remove the comment is the error still at the same line or has it moved? Have you tried importing it via the command line?

Comment: I am very embarrassed to report back that it was actually some non-visible character at the beginning of each comment. And the reason the statements still worked when run individually was because I was not running them with the comments. Thanks so much for the help =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the comment by Fung:

> ...it was actually some non-visible character at the beginning of each
>   comment. And the reason the statements still worked when run
>   individually was because I was not running them with the comments